# android studio -gradle build not finishing

Tags: 15.10, android, android-studio, gradle

I installed android studio for the first time and tried to use windows installed java sdk here but that produced many errors..So i deleted that folder and installed the java sdk for ubuntu from sdk manager
but the gradle build is not finishing:

[image]

I  deleted the android studio folder and reinstalled  it but still showing the same error.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, did you solved that?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I was forced to do a fresh install